# Power BI: Confirm the text of three columns is ="yes"

Tags: text, powerbi, controls, multiple-columns

I have the below formula to check that if the value for a record in three column is equal to yes, then 1, otherwise 0. The error sats the syntax for "," is incorrect, why?

`SanityCheck_APAC&EM = IF('Connectivity Coverage analysis xlsx_https://iontradingcom sharepoint com/teams/F'[APAC]="yes" && 'Connectivity Coverage analysis xlsx_https://iontradingcom sharepoint com/teams/F'[Emerging Markets])="yes" && RELATED(components_mkt[pacific_rim])="yes",1,0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the '(' and ')' is the problem? You open them 2x and close them 3x.

```
SanityCheck_APAC&EM = IF
(
  'Connectivity Coverage analysis xlsx_https://iontradingcom sharepoint com/teams/F'[APAC]="yes" 
  && 'Connectivity Coverage analysis xlsx_https://iontradingcom sharepoint com/teams/F'[Emerging Markets]
)
  ="yes" 
  && RELATED
(
  components_mkt[pacific_rim]
)
  ="yes",1,0
)
```